# OnSeekBarChangeListener always evaluates to null in Android

Tags: java, android, listener

I have an android program that I am making with 4 seekbars, and 4 textviews to accompany each seekbar.  Right now, I am trying to make each textview's contents equal to the integer progress of the seekbars.  This is my code as it stands, and I have tried many ways to properly implement the OnSeekBarChangeListener, but LogCat still shows that it is null when sb1-sb4 sets their OnSeekBarChangeListener to OnSeekBarProgress.  Please help me identify my problem :(

```
public class TippopotamusActivity extends Activity {
    SeekBar sb1;
    SeekBar sb2;
    SeekBar sb3;
    SeekBar sb4;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sb2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    sb3 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    sb4 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar4);

    sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

OnSeekBarChangeListener OnSeekBarProgress =
        new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar s, int progress, boolean touch){
            if(s.getId() == R.id.seekBar1)
            {
                tv1.setText(progress);
            }
            else if(s.getId() == R.id.seekBar2)
            {
                tv2.setText(progress);
            }
            else if(s.getId() == R.id.seekBar3)
            {
                tv3.setText(progress);
            }
            else
            {
                tv4.setText(progress);
            }
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar s){

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar s){

        }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `setContentView(R.layout.main);` before initializing your variables. Your `onCreate` method should look like this

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sb2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    sb3 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    sb4 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar4);

    sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
    sb4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarProgress);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, the apk will actually install and run now, but when i attempt to move the SeekBar around, the app crashes.  Do you happen to have any clue as to what I did wrong?

Comment: @mchao92: probably some NullPointerException. What is the stacktrace in logcat?

Comment: @mchao92. Every thing is looking fine but try using tv3.setText(""+progress); as setText takes string input. If it did not solves the problem, send the logcat of exception you are getting.

Comment: @Muhammad: you are correct! i just had to call ToString passing in my "progress" and it works like a charm.  thank you very much!