# Android - VerticalSeekBar - onStopTrackingTouch() not working

Tags: java, android, listener, progress, seekbar

everyone! I'm new to Android development and I'm having troubles while trying to set an specific position to the seek bar's thumb.

I want to set the seek bar's progress to it's initial position (in this case 4) when the user releases the thumb, in order to do this, I'm trying to use the method onStopTrackingTouch, but it looks like it's not being called when the user releases the seek bar thumb. There are no errors indicated by Eclipse, the program runs normally, the only problem is that when I release the thumb, it does not return to the initial position.

Detail: I'm using a Vertical Seek Bar, can this be the reason of the problem?

Here's the activity code:

```
package renatox.play.bluetoothcommander;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private VerticalSeekBar acelerador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sets the Main Activity layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Gets the VerticalSeekBar
    acelerador = (VerticalSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.acelerador);

    acelerador
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
// I've tried using SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() and VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    acelerador.setProgress(4);
                    Log.i("Acelerador", "O usuário soltou o acelerador");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    Log.i("Acelerador", "O usuário pegou o acelerador");
                }

                // Pega os valores do acelerador quando mudam
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1,
                        boolean arg2) {
                    int velocidade = acelerador.getProgress();
                    Log.i("Acelerador", "Velocidade atual: " + velocidade);
                }
            });
}
```

Here's the xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fundo"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<renatox.play.bluetoothcommander.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/acelerador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:max="8"
    android:maxHeight="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:progress="4"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the VerticalSeekBar class

```
package renatox.play.bluetoothcommander;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

protected OnSeekBarChangeListener changeListener;

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {

    super(context);

}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);

}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
        int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    c.rotate(-90);

    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

    super.onDraw(c);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isEnabled()) {

        return false;

    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        setSelected(true);
        setPressed(true);
        if (changeListener != null)
            changeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        setSelected(false);
        setPressed(false);
        if (changeListener != null)
            changeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        int progress = getMax()
                - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
        setProgress(progress);
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
        if (changeListener != null)
            changeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

Can anyone give me a hint of what might be happening?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149009/onseekbarchangelistener-always-evaluates-to-null-in-android

Comment: Where do you define `VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`?

Comment: MalaKa, you're right, that was the reason why it was not working! I've fixed and now it's just fine, thank you very much!

Comment: And sicachester, thank you for the help also!

Comment: @Renato Henz , Can you please share how you resolved this problem?

Comment: Hey, man! It's been a long time since I finished working in this project, but if I'm not mistaken, I've just added this to the "VerticalSeekBar.java":


    _@Override
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener) {
        this.changeListener = mListener;
    }_


If you need any further help, please tell me. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would post this as an official "answer" since it helped me with my code. (answered by Renato Henz)

> I've just added this to the "VerticalSeekBar.java": `@Override public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener) { this.changeListener = mListener; }` If you need any further help, please tell me. Good luck with your code!

I found that adding in this code, along with the code previously mentioned, helps with some issues:

```
 @Override
 public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
      super.setProgress(progress); 
      onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I add in aboce setOnSeekBarChangeListner code in the VerticalSeekBar.java, the myControl.setOnseekBarChangeListener code stops working altogether. i.e. OnProgrressChanged stops.
I am trying to enable the code in my activity to the Toast fires (just a placeholder)

```
@Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Toast.makeText(APG.this, "Change OD Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. Add a new question instead and link to this one if they are both related and people will have an easier time finding your question and helping you out.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you change your code like this it will work.

```
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             super.onTouchEvent(event);
            // your code here.
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define `OnSeekBarChangeListener` in `VerticalSeekbar` then it will work

Try it in VerticalSeekBar like

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener onChangeListener;
    @Override
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener onChangeListener){
        this.onChangeListener = onChangeListener;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have missed out, just call within onTouchEvent.

```
super.onTouchEvent(event);
```